# Glass mapper Editable() with List<> items not showing in edit mode

Tags: model-view-controller, sitecore, glass-mapper

I have a list of items I'm reading out of sitecore and looping in my View. The items are quite stright forward and are simply output as a series of

**Model:**

```
[SitecoreType(TemplateId = "{1044CFB5-2B85-4A8D-9DCC-34764D2AF5B3}", AutoMap = true)]
    public class Footer 
    {
        public virtual Item Item { get; set; }
        [SitecoreInfo(SitecoreInfoType.Path)]
        public virtual string Path { get; set; }
        [SitecoreField(FieldName ="Copyright Text First",FieldType = SitecoreFieldType.SingleLineText)]
        public virtual string CopyrightTextFirst { get; set; }

        [SitecoreField(FieldName ="Copyright Text Last",FieldType = SitecoreFieldType.SingleLineText)]
        public virtual string CopyrightTextLast { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<BrandNavigaion> lstBrandNav {get;set; }
    }
     [SitecoreType(TemplateId = "{A87A00B1-E6DB-45AB-8B54-636FEC3B5523}", AutoMap = true)]
    public class BrandNavigaion
    {
        public virtual Item Item { get; set; }
       [SitecoreInfo(SitecoreInfoType.Path)]
        public virtual string Path { get; set; }
        //[SitecoreField(FieldName = "Item name")]
        public virtual string Itemname { get; set; }
        [SitecoreField(FieldName = "Destination URL",FieldType=SitecoreFieldType.GeneralLink)]
        public virtual string DestinationURL { get; set; }
        [SitecoreField(FieldName = "Is Active ", FieldType = SitecoreFieldType.Checkbox)]
        public virtual bool IsActive  { get; set; }
        public virtual IEnumerable<Sitecore.Data.Items.Item> Children { get; set; }
        //public virtual IEnumerable<BrandSubNavigaion> Children { get; set; }
    }
```

View

```
 @foreach (var item in Model.lstBrandNav)
                    {
                            <li>
                                <a href="@item.DestinationURL">
                                    @Editable(item, i => i.Itemname)
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        if (item.Children != null && item.Children.Count() > 0)
                        {
                            <li class="">
                                <a data-toggle="dropdown">Associate Sites <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
                                <ul>
                                    @foreach (var childitem in item.Children)
                                    {
                                        <li><a href="">@childitem.Name</a></li>
                                    }
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        }
                    }
```

result Showing correct in preview mode:
[image]

But in edit mode showing like below

[image]

Please help me, what is wrong in my code.

Comment: Are your child pages published? In all language versions?

Comment: Here I used  only default language, no more languages. Thank you.

Comment: Do you have more than 1 site? Do you have `sc_site=website` in your url?

Comment: No yaar, I have only one site.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you don't need to have 2 fields DestinationUrl and ItemName. 
You can have on DestionationUrl also value of the ItemName. DestinationUrl is a general link field and it contains url and text field.

And you can have multiple properties for a General Link field:

[image]

Can you change in your code

```
    SitecoreField(FieldName = "Destination URL",FieldType=SitecoreFieldType.GeneralLink)]
    public virtual Glass.Mapper.Sc.Fields.Link DestinationURL { get; set; }
```

and render your link in this way:

```
      @using (BeginRenderLink(item, x => x.DestinationUrl, new { @class = "your class" }, isEditable: Sitecore.Context.PageMode.IsPageEditor))
        {
            @(item.DestinationUrl != null ? item.DestinationUrl.Text : "Select a link")
        }
```

BeginRenderLink is from Glass :

```
   /// <summary>
    /// Render HTML for a link with contents
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The model type</typeparam>
    /// <param name="model">The model</param>
    /// <param name="field">The link field to user</param>
    /// <param name="attributes">Any additional link attributes</param>
    /// <param name="isEditable">Make the link editable</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public virtual RenderingResult BeginRenderLink<T>(T model, Expression<Func<T, object>> field,
        object attributes = null, bool isEditable = false)
    {
        return GlassHtml.BeginRenderLink(model, field, this.Output, attributes, isEditable);

    }
```

Comment: in your view you have to use the code the code with beginRenderLink. You need to add: @using Glass.Mapper.Sc.Web.Mvc in your view

Comment: I update codes as like above, but am getting following error:  CS1061: 'CassiaMvc.Models.BrandNavigaion' does not contain a definition for 'DestinationUrl' and no extension method 'DestinationUrl' accepting a first argument of type 'CassiaMvc.Models.BrandNavigaion' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: :) can you change from DestinationUrl to DestinationURL. You have different name in View and Model

Comment: I have same name in view and model.

Comment: We can't give you entire solution to solve your issue. We give you some tips and tricks and you need  to fix yourself your issues.

Comment: Please see my entire code in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36181586/glass-mapper-general-link-button-not-working-in-preview-mode?noredirect=1#comment60001397_36181586,  and please suggest me.